# Error when installing Money Manager Ex

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I'm trying to install Money Manager Ex (mmex), and I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mmex depends: libwxgtkw.0-0-unofficial (> = 2.9.0) but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. There is a thread on their support forums about it, which I used to get my install working

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.1/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt-get install curl
curl http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial
```

http://forum.moneymanagerex.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5528

Answer (score 0):

I am a little new to linux. I had the same problem, and this resolved it for me :

1- I did like previous post, except I replaced libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial with libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial (since this was the error I had)

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.1/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
sudo apt-get install curl
curl http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial
```

2- I downloaded deb package from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/moneymanagerex/files/moneymanagerex/Version%201.1.0/mmex_1.1.0_amd64.deb/download
(this is the version I chose, there are others)

3- install using ubuntu software center

Answer (score 0):

The curl installation didn't work for me, so I've downloaded and installed the `libtiff4` package ([libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb direct link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb)) and now it works.

More `libtiff4` packages at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/.